# CSS: Select outside element as well

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<div><p class="inside"></div>
```

Main objective is to select `class("inside")` and it will select `div` as well. How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is no way and as @Keatinge pointed out, duplicate

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/parent/ might help you